# Check whether the elements of a column with list values are present in another list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column called `antecedent` (list values) and I would like to return True or False for rows where all elements are present in another list called `itemset`.

Example `itemset` :

```py
['Investimento Fundos_commodities', 'Investimento Fundos Multimercado','Emprestimo _educacao', 'Investimento CDB']
```

Example `antecedent`:

```py
['Investimento Fundos_commodities', 'Investimento Fundos']
# Desired Output : False, because we don't have the presence of the Investment Funds value in itemset.
```

Other Example `antecedent` :

```py
['Investimento Fundos_commodities', 'Investimento CDB']
# Desired Output : True, because we have the presence of the two values in itemset.
```

I was only able to print the elements that are present in `itemset`, but I was not able to do this check for elements that are not present to return True or False.

```py
df_itemset['antecedent'].map(lambda antecedents : [x for x in antecedents if x in itemset])

# Output :
# 16     [Investimento Fundos_commodities]
# 23     [Investimento Fundos_commodities]
# 4     [Investimento Fundos_commodities]
# 26     [Investimento Fundos_commodities]
# 30     [Investimento Fundos_commodities]
                     ...                
# 138                   [Investimento CDB]
# 139                   [Investimento CDB]
# 140                   [Investimento CDB]
# 141                   [Investimento CDB]
# 142                   [Investimento CDB]
# Name: antecedent, Length: 99, dtype: object
```

Comment: If antecedent is ['A', 'B'] and itemset is ['A', 'B', 'C'], your condition is true or false?

Comment: @Corralien True because we have A and B in itemset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` and `issubset` predicate:

```
data = {'antecedent': [['Investimento Fundos_commodities', 'Investimento Fundos'], 
                       ['Investimento Fundos_commodities', 'Investimento CDB']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['issubset'] = df['antecedent'].apply(lambda x: set(x).issubset(itemset))
print(out)

# Output:
                                               antecedent  issubset
0  [Investimento Fundos_commodities, Investimento Fundos]     False
1     [Investimento Fundos_commodities, Investimento CDB]      True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
df_itemset['antecedent'].map(
  lambda antecedents : len([x for x in antecedents if x not in itemset])
) == 0
```

It calculates the number of antecedents which are not in itemset, so it is > 0 if and only if your condition does not hold.